# htaccess redirect error to a subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Trying to redirect this **always** works:

```
RewriteRule ^user/(.*) view_channel.php?user=$1 [nc]
```

The problem, trying to redirect the statement below **alone** works but when **combined with the above statement** it doesn't work (the result was a blank page):

```
RewriteRule ^user/videos/(.*) user_videos.php?user=$1 [nc]
```

More details about .htaccess:

```
Options All -Indexes
FileETag MTime Size
Options +FollowSymlinks  -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
<FilesMatch "\.(db|inc|tmpl|h|ihtml|sql|ini|configuration|config|class|bin|spd|theme|module|cfg|cpl|tmp|log|err|inc.php|class.php)$">
order allow,deny
satisfy all
</FilesMatch>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your regex `^user/(.*)` also matches a URI like `/user/videos/something`.

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^user/videos/([^/]+)/?$ user_videos.php?user=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/?$ view_channel.php?user=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: +1 for the additional conditions etc. Always learning from you how to do it better. :)

Answer (score 2):

The rules are not mutually incompatible. Nor are they final. Change them like this:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+) view_channel.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^user/videos/([^/]+) user_videos.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
```

`[^/]+` matches one or more character that is not a `/`. This ensures that the first rule cannot match the second pattern, which it did with the `.*`, as that matches any characters, including `/` of course.

Comment: @anubhava, but you were faster, and added more details to the rule, so you deserve to get the vote.

Comment: zx81:answered 10 mins ago. anubhava: answered 9 mins ago.

Answer (score 0):

The second `RewriteRule` statement is matched against already rewritten url.